# SQL using fallback column for match

Tags: sql, coalesce, short-circuiting

Say I have a table in an sql database like

```
name    age  shoesize
---------------------
tom      20      NULL
dick   NULL         4
harry    30         5
```

and I want an SQL statement that selects names that have age == X, or as a fallback, if no such names exist, use those with shoe size == Y. In other words, in this table, for X=20,Y=4 I should only get 'tom', while for X=25,Y=4 I should get only 'dick'. I can't do that with

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE age = 20 OR shoe size = 4;
```

because that will select both tom and dick. I'm currently using

```
SELECT COALESCE ((SELECT name FROM tab WHERE age = 20),(SELECT name FROM tab WHERE shoesize = 4));
```

but is there a neater way? Also using coalesce like this doesn't allow me to get the whole row - i.e. I can't use `SELECT * FROM tab`, I can only select a single name.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: It's a general SQL question, I think. I'm switching between sqlite, mySQL, and Postgres - would like it to work in all of them

Comment: I don't understand why X=20, Y=4 should only return 'tom' when 'dick' has a NULL age.  Are you saying that if you find at least one match with the first condition, you don't want to check for the second condition?

Comment: Exactly. I only want to fallback to an alternative column when no rows match the first condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ORDER BY` and `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` or some similar clause:

```
SELECT name
FROM tab
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN age = X THEN 1
               WHEN shoesize = Y THEN 2
               ELSE 3
          END)
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Some databases spell `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` like `LIMIT` or `TOP` or even something else.

Comment: An interesting alternative, thanks. I'm no SQL expert, so I'm wondering if your statement short-circuits, so that shoe size is not examined if there is an age = X match? And is ORDER BY slower than multiple SELECTs?

Comment: @user2667066 . . . No there is no short-circuiting.  Whether a single statement with `order by` is faster or slower than multiple selects depends on the size of the data (and perhaps other factors).